# Finding the function from given data.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function defined for all $x \ge$ 1 and satisfying $f(1)=1$ and $f'(x)$= $\frac{1}{x^2 + (f(x))^2}$. Then find $f(x)$.

What I tried to do was separate the variable to get it in a form where I could integrate both the sides and apply the given condition to get the function. But that didn't take me anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could do some kind of transform to polar coordinates? For example, $x^2 + (f(x))^2 = r^2$.

Comment: This is given as an assignment question and we haven't been taught polar coordinates yet. If you could show me how to do it with polar coordinates, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

It's a special tricky type of differential equations. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)